# How to ensure Bootstrap columns align properly when wrapped

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Boostrap layout that has four centred columns when the screen is large, two columns when small, and one column when extra small. This works ok except when viewed at the small screen size when the columns do not wrap how I want them to.

On a large screen it looks like:

```html
>zzz    xxx    yyy    aaa
```

On an extra small screen it looks like:

```html
>zzz
>xxx
>yyy
>aaa
```

But on a small screen it looks like:

```js
>            zzz
>xxx         yyy
>aaa
```

I need it to look like:

```html
zzz      xxx
yyy      aaa
```

My Boostrap code is:

```html
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center">zzz</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center">xxx</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center">yyy</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center">aaa</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">         
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: you realise you have 6 dives here? that means that the first empty one will behave like the first in the grid.

Comment: Ah thanks. I see what is going wrong now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is actually:

(empty) zzz xxx yyy aaa (empty)

Your md allows for all 6 columns in a row (2 cols each), so that works fine (offsetting the first seemingly by 2 columns due to it being empty)

Your xs makes all of them 12 columns wide so this will also seemingly work as they all stretch across (with a blank column on top and below).

Your sm is working correctly but it looks as though it is not due to the extra columns you have.

Either remove these empty divs or if you really need them do this:

```
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">zzz</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">xxx</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">yyy</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">aaa</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">         
        </div>
    </div>
```

[EDIT - using offsets]

If you are simply looking for offsets at the md value, this should work instead of cluttering your mark-up with empty divs.

```
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
             <div class="text-center">zzz</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">xxx</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">yyy</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center">aaa</div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I remove the empty divs the columns get offset to the left at md size so are no longer centred. However your suggestion of changing from col-sm-6 to col-sm-12 for the empty divs worked brilliantly! Thanks.

Comment: if you need to offset, perhaps look at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Please check my edit above for an offset example. should work exactly as you need, example: http://www.bootply.com/hIqARO7GZq

Answer (score 0):

You have a blank div. Remove that and it will work as intended.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">     </div>
```

Comment: That fixes the problem with the alignment at sm sizes but the md size is now no longer centred but offset to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Class `col-md-*` have a minimal space. If you use `min-height: 0px;`, it will may help you.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center" style="min-height: 0px;">
```